# await and promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get birthdays from my Firestore database. I am trying to add them to an array and then make changes to my UI after the call is finished. I read a few docs and came up with the below code, but I see no errors in the console, and the last `console.log` is not printing. What is happening here?

```
async function getFirestoreBirthdays() {
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    var birthdaysArr = []

    db.collection("birthdays").orderBy("date", "desc").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            birthdaysArr.push(doc.data());
        })
    })

    var firestoreBirthdays = await Promise.all(birthdaysArr);
    console.log(firestoreBirthdays)

}
```

Comment: Since you're using async/await, don't you want to `await` the promise returned by `get()` instead of using `then` on it?  Right now, your function doesn't wait for the query to complete before logging the result.  `then` doesn't block the execution of your code.  Also, you're using `Promise.all` to collect things that aren't promises, which doesn't make any sense.  You just have one promise to deal with, which is the result of `get()`, so there is no need for `Promise.all`.

Comment: Even if `doc.data()` returns a promise, this wouldn't work because `birthdaysArr` is filled in asynchronously. Since you don't `await` the `get()`, it will be empty when you call `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Rewrite this using `await` for everything instead of mixing `await` and `.then()` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

What I see you're doing in the code right now, you are mixing `async/await` with `then` callback but without a `catch` block. Please note that it's one approach or the other, never both. If you want to declare your `getFirestoreBirthdays` function as an `async` function, then you have to use `await` to wait for all promises to be resolved so you can get the result of the request.

When you're using a `forEach` in case of asynchronous calls, it will not work for sure as you might expect. Please note that `then` doesn't block the execution of your code. So you cannot get the result immediately. Besides that, your last line of code:

```
var firestoreBirthdays = await Promise.all(birthdaysArr);
```

Tries to collect things that aren't available yet. To solve this, you only have to use a single promise that is the result of the `get()` call. That's it. There is no need to use `Promise.all()` at all.